# MYSQL workbench error : select is not valid at this position for this server version expecting '(' WITH

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to use DISTINCT for my this query and i am getting error:
select is not valid at this position for this server version expecting '(' with

When i was not using the mcat.strCategoryName column i was getting 39 rows which is correct data. And after adding it into query, it giving me 156 rows, it means "mcat.strCategoryName" repeating for every 39 records.

```
select ser.nServiceId as sid,
ser.nVendorId as vid,
ser.strServiceName as sn,
DISTINCT mcat.strCategoryName as cate,
ser.strServiceDescription as sd,ser.strCreatedOn as co 
from tblservicedetails ser
LEFT JOIN tblbusinessdetails bs ON bs.nVendorId = ser.nVendorId
LEFT JOIN tblvendorbusinesscategory vbc ON bs.nBusinessDetailsId = vbc.nBusinessDetailsId
LEFT JOIN tblmaincategory mcat ON vbc.nMainCategoryId = mcat.nMainCategoryId
where ser.nVendorId=2;
```

Comment: You can't have a `DISTINCT` on a single selected field. It's either after `SELECT` or not at all.

Comment: Where distinct is used it has to be after the select and before any column names and it is distinct over all columns - which is probably not what you want.(but you haven't said what you do want)

Comment: @P.Salmon actully i am getting repeated data for mcat.strCategoryName column, that's why i used it. Is there any other method for doing the same?

Comment: @P.Salmon i updated my question

Comment: it is still not working because of the DISTINCT as @Aioros stated

Comment: @nbk exactly. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to remove the Distinct and add a GROUP BY, and see if that helps you further. But  without any data, you understand that you can only receive general advice see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk only 3 rows is returning :/

Comment: Please create sample and uodate your actual query see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query i will see what i can do